# I am getting OAuth2 server connection error few times in Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I am using Laravel framework for my application. Every day few times it is throwing the OAuth2 authentication error and it says "The user credentials were incorrect" but after sometime automatically it is connecting. Anybody can help me on this why it is happening.

```
local.ERROR: League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The user credentials were incorrect. in /var/www/html/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Grant/PasswordGrant.php(98): League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Grant/PasswordGrant.php(53): League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant->validateUser(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Laravel\Passport\Bridge\Client))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php(209): League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant->respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse), Object(DateInterval))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(62): League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer->respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/HandlesOAuthErrors.php(25): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(63): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->withErrorHandling(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(47): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->issueToken(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController), 'issueToken')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /var/www/html/app/Http/Middleware/PassportCustomProvider.php(23): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\PassportCustomProvider->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/app/Http/Middleware/Language.php(21): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\Language->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/app/Http/Middleware/PassportCustomGuardAccessToken.php(47): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\PassportCustomGuardAccessToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /var/www/html/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Comment: I think you are using Laravel Passport

Comment: Which grant are you using, how are you calling it? give more info

Comment: We are using Laravel Passport for restful web services.

Comment: I think, this error because of user credentials were wrong

Comment: If APP_DEBUG = false, it will not throw exception, just will return 401 or 403 code

Comment: But exception is logged in your log files

Comment: This issue happens few times and after some time it is connecting automatically. Do you have any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: i have the same issue, any solution???